# Fuel misting during refuel

Tags: diesel, fuel-tank, jaguar

So I recently received my new company car, a Jaguar XE. When refuelling the car there is quite a lot of diesel misting coming out of the tank. I've never had this before on any diesel car and I'm wondering if it's normal. I've read some posts on other forums and found this as a possible cause:

[image: fuel misting cause]

[Source](https://www.xeforums.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=679&start=20#p4026)

While it might be normal, It's annoying and it makes my hands stink. I also noticed the fuel hose isn't going in as deep as on other cars that I'm used to, this might be the cause of the vapour recirculation system of the fuel pump not working. Anyone else ever had this issue?

Comment: Most filling stations provide thin plastic gloves - does wearing them help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no actual maintenance or repair issue to solve.

Comment: @SolarMike While the plastic gloves might solve the stinky issue, it's not a real solution to the problem :).

Comment: @CharlieRB I know from the XE forums that some people did get a repair, they got a new fuel entry system or however you want to call it. So it actually is somewhat related to an repair.

Comment: I would say that problems where "no action is required" can still be considered maintenance/repair issues. For example, for https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/45965/is-it-normal-to-hear-noise-from-brakes-when-turning-the-steering-wheel-at-stands the answer can very well be "no action required", yet nobody voted to close this question.

Comment: @Bram you posted the "real" cause in your post - about the swirl pot and the temperature difference, how you control the temperature difference - good question. As to how you could prevent the smell on your hands I did make a suggestion for you.

Comment: Your question is not about how perform maintenance or repair anything. You are asking "Anyone else ever had this issue", which more open ended or kind of a rant. I am not trying to be difficult, just following the guidelines in [What types of questions should I avoid asking](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Charlie is correct. And Solar is an expert on Jaguar. As far as I'm concerned gloves should do the trick. For the rest seek help under warranty.

Comment: Fill tank at a slower rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this issue with an audi, although I wouldn't really call it an issue, more of an annoyance. I solved it by turning the fuel nozzle clockwise a bit and found that it went in a little bit farther, and I didn't get misting anymore.  However when filling a diesel car you will always get a bit of diesel on your hands, it's inevitable, so if you don't like eau de diesel use the gloves that are supplied at most stations. I have a pack in the back of my merc in case I get to a station that has run out, they are dirt cheap and handy for other things too like when filling oil.

Comment: I'll try turning the fuel nozzle next time I'm going to fuel, if this solved the major misting i'm happy! I know that you always get a bit "eau de diesel" but I don't need to be covered in it. The gloves are always available at the stations I go so that's not an issue.

Comment: That does sound like more than should be, if that doesn't solve it you may want to talk to the dealer, after all it is under warranty.

Comment: My car will be at the dealership beginning of next month, so I'll ask to be sure.  With "covered in it" I ment the misting ofc, it quite a lot of "smoke" that is coming out when fuelling. And also because the nozzle is not going in as deep as I'm used to, I'm not comfortable yet with using the fuel lock so I don't need to keep holding the hose.

Comment: You could try squeezing the filler less as well, a slower fuel flow may reduce the mist.

Comment: Good tips! Will also try that next time.

Comment: Where are you based? Just go to a station where they provide filling service. You don't want the stench, pay a dollar or 2 in tips.